# Why dialogue box doesn't appear in login form in android?

Tags: php, android, mysql, android-alertdialog

I am making an app, that simply registers a user through username and password, and logs in through user id, that is assign to the user and send the record in mysql database. I am successfully able to save the record in the database but when I want to login I can't do so, it even does not go to the next activity. When I click on the login button nor it shows a dialogue box that the id or password is incorrect, it does neither of them. I also have two radio buttons where the user have to choose as whom they are logging in. Why the user is not logging in or shows dialogue box? How could I add a value of radio button in the database?

Here is my code:

> background.java

```
public class backgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
    AlertDialog alertDialog;
    Context ctx;

    backgroundTask(Context ctx) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Login successful");
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String reg_url = "http://192.168.10.9/app/register.php";
    String login_url = "http://192.168.10.9/app/login.php";
        String method = params[0];
        if (method.equals("register")) {
            String username = params[1];
            String password = params[2];
            String phone_no = params[3];
            try {
                URL url = new URL(reg_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                //httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);  
                OutputStream OS = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(OS, "UTF-8"));
                String data = URLEncoder.encode("username", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(username, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                        URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                        URLEncoder.encode("phone_no", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(phone_no, "UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                OS.close();
                InputStream IS = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                IS.close();
                //httpURLConnection.connect();  
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                return "Registration Successful";
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else if(method.equals("login"))
        {
            String id = params[1];
            String password = params[2];
            try {
                URL url = new URL(login_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream,"UTF-8"));
                String data = URLEncoder.encode("id","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(id,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                        URLEncoder.encode("password","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(password,"UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();
                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
                String response = "";
                String line = "";
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!=null)
                {
                    response+= line;
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                return response;
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }



    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if(result.equals("Registration Successful"))
        {
            Toast.makeText(ctx, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else
        {
        alertDialog.setMessage(result);
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    }

}
```

this is login.java:

```
public class login extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

Button bLogin;
    TextView registerLink;
    EditText  etUserId, etPassword;
    String id, password;
    RadioButton  rdParent, rdChild;
    RadioGroup rg;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        etUserId = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUserId);
        etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
        registerLink = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.registerLink);


        registerLink.setOnClickListener(this);
      // selectItem();

    }
```

I have commented the radio buttons, because I thought may be these radio buttons are not letting me login:

```
 /* public void selectItem()
    {

        rg = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rg);
        rdParent = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rdParent);
        rdChild = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rdChild);
        bLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bLogin);
        bLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               if ( rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.rdParent)
                {
                    Intent rdParentIntent = new Intent(login.this,synchronization.class);
                    startActivity(rdParentIntent );
                }
                else if(rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.rdChild)
               {
                   Intent rdChildIntent = new Intent(login.this,emergency.class);
                   startActivity(rdChildIntent);
               }
            }
        });

        } */
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.registerLink:
                Intent registerIntent = new Intent(login.this,register.class);
                startActivity(registerIntent);
                break;
            case R.id.bLogin:
                id = etUserId.getText().toString();
                password = etPassword.getText().toString();
                String method = "login";
                backgroundTask bTask = new backgroundTask(this);
                bTask.execute(method, id, password);
                break;
        }
        }
    }
```

login.php:

```
<?php
require"db_connect.php";
$id = $_POST["id"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
$query = "select * from user where id like '$id' and password like '$password'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0) {
    echo "login successful";
    }       
    else{
        echo "incorrect id or password";
    }
```

?>

Comment: you are suppose to call `Intent` in `onPostExecute`. aren't you?

Comment: i dont know what you're talking about because i followed a tutorial, it would be better if you show me the way to do it. +vrundpurohit

Comment: oh yeah i got your point, no if i call the intent to start a new activity in login.java it still doesnot work. @vrund purohit

Comment: where are you setting `onClickListener` on your `bLogin`?

Comment: in selectItem() function where radio buttons are specified, the one i have commented.@vrundpurohit

Comment: @vrundpurohit to get the post value can we use getText().toString() for id or do we have to parse it first? because i feel that is why it is not logging in.

Answer (score 0):

Tried your code and works in the way you wanted for me.
So can you try the below one 

        `@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx).create();
            alertDialog.setTitle("Login successful");
            alertDialog.setMessage(s);
            alertDialog.show();
        }`